# web.config iis7.0 integrated system.webserver handlers and modules

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Below is my web.config, I'm very new at web.config and configuring it, but I was able to find a little data on this, can someone point out what is wrong with my web.config and what it takes to change it?

```
    <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
        </handlers>
        <modules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule,System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I did find this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx
but I'm not sure honestly what to do.

Comment: Do you won to learn about, or make it run ? This line can not be in this session in integrate mode. The most simple way is to make a reset of the handlers from inside the iis and it going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are wanting to know exactly but the default for the web.config is the following:

```
 <system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules>
    <remove name="ScriptModule" />
    <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
    <remove name="ScriptResource" />
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```